# throwing error on placing a new order

Tags: virtocommerce

i have create a new store and add some item on that store. more than 2 or 3 times i can place order but now when i checkout my cart it shows me error.

```
at VirtoCommerce.Client.Api.OrderModuleApi.<OrderModuleProcessOrderPaymentsAsyncWithHttpInfo>d__52.MoveNext() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vc-community-master(1)\vc-community-master\SDK\DotNet\VirtoCommerce.Client\Api\OrderModuleApi.cs:line 2097 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at VirtoCommerce.Client.Api.OrderModuleApi.<OrderModuleProcessOrderPaymentsAsync>d__51.MoveNext() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vc-community-master(1)\vc-community-master\SDK\DotNet\VirtoCommerce.Client\Api\OrderModuleApi.cs:line 2038 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at VirtoCommerce.Storefront.Controllers.CartController.<GetOrderProcessingResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vc-community-master(1)\vc-community-master\STOREFRONT\VirtoCommerce.Storefront\Controllers\CartController.cs:line 355 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at VirtoCommerce.Storefront.Controllers.CartController.<CreateOrderJson>d__22.MoveNext() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vc-community-master(1)\vc-community-master\STOREFRONT\VirtoCommerce.Storefront\Controllers\CartController.cs:line 271 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of payment method did you choose?

Comment: hi Andrew Orlov i am using test type.

Comment: Well, I need more information to reproduce your case. Can you update your question with step-by-step use case?

Comment: Can you replicate the above error in the demo environment? http://demo.virtocommerce.com